# Why is the second line executed n (n + 1 / 2)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

```
1. for i = 1 to n
2.    for j = i + 1 to n
        [...]
```

Why does my textbook say that the second line is executed n (n + 1 / 2) + 1 times?

I know that the first line will be executed n + 1 times because the + 1 will break the loop

Comment: You probably mean `n*(n+1)/2` (so the `/2` is not part of `1` but of `(n+1)`?

Comment: Yes I mean this, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nested loop iteration count will be reduced by one each time ( see the picture below). Nevertheless , the whole code is in O(n^2).  O(n*( (n+1)/2) = O( n*n/2+n/2) =O(n^2)

```
n=5
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

Comment: It will be reduced by 1, this I understand, but why the divided by 2? It doesn't make sense where the division by 2 comes from

Comment: @user2426691: the surface of a triangle is its base times its height divided by two.

Comment: Or you can think of it as a still of an arithmetic progression https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Comment: Btw, are sure that the book says n(n+1/2) and not n*(n+1)/2

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1):

The outer loop will result in *n* iterations of the inner loop. Each of these iterations will result in *n-i* loops. Since *i* ranges from *i* to *n* this thus results in a sum that looks like:

```
n + n-1 + n-2 + ... 1
```

This is a known sum. The sum of i with i from 1 to n is the same as:

```
 n
---
\         n * (n + 1)
/    i  = -----------
---           2
i=1
```